# mysqli db connect class not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Dear All I am trying to create mysqli db connect class, this is my first php class I am writing, I don't know where I am doing wrong, please someone please correct me

This is my

```
         <?php
                 class Database
                 {

                     private static $m_pInstance; private $link;

                     private $db_host ='localhost';
                     private $db_user = 'root';
                     private $db_pass = 'rootpass';
                     private $db_name = 'mydb';


                     private function __construct() 
                     {
                       $this->link = new mysqli_connect($this->db_host,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass,$this->db_name);
                       return $this->link;
                     }


                     public static function getInstance()
                     {
                         if (!self::$m_pInstance)
                         {
                             self::$m_pInstance = new Database();
                         }
                         return self::$m_pInstance;
                     }

               // here I would like to switch db
                public function mydb($query)
                {
                $this->link->mysqli_select_db($query);
                }

              // Here I want to run my raw query...
                     public function query($query)
                     {
                        return $this->link->mysqli_query($query);
                     }

                  }

         ?>
```

I would like to start query like this

```
  $first_class = Database::getInstance();

  $result = $first_class -> query("select * from mytable");
```

Please someone correct me..and Please put comments I would like to understand control flow here...truly speaking I am very uncomfortable with `$x = $this->somefun($sql)`

Comment: This is a very helpful question can we re-open it I would like to start a bounty on it asking for further explanation on the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the procedural instantiation method instead of the OO method to create your connection. Remember, when you create something as an object (using the new keyword), the magic __construct method is called on that class. See [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

So instead of

```
$this->link = new mysqli_connect($this->db_host,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass,$this->db_name);
```

You need to use

```
$this->link = new mysqli($this->db_host,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass,$this->db_name);
```

Also, this method may be unecessary since you are selecting the database when you create the connection.

```
// here I would like to switch db
public function mydb($query)
{
    $this->link->mysqli_select_db($query);
}
```

e
Go through the docs and learn the OO representations of the various mysqli methods and use this in place of the procedural functions and that will solve a lot of your problems.

Nice job on using a singleton object by the way. Some may vehemently disagree with me, but I think for database connection management it's a good way to go. One other method you have is PDO connection caching, but for something basic like this a singleton is just fine.

Please comment if you are receiving any other errors.

Comment: Singleton adds extra code for no benefit (most libraries will reuse connections automatically) and potential annoyance (one day you need a second connection and you're stuck). Just my opinion :)

Comment: If you aren't using a library, it's a good method. That's why I say for this application it's a good usage. Libraries and frameworks on the other hand do things their own way. I usually recommend people build in lots of functionality into their singleton (such as connection pool management) to avoid these problems, but since he's just a beginner, I'll let that slide ;) It's really not an uncommon practice, up until a few bloggers posted "zomg singletons r bad"

Comment: Alright, I admit the term library can be confusing. Call it "builtin PHP extension" if you prefer.

Comment: lol yeah, that's why I mention PDO caching, but that's a whole different answer. This demonstrates an understanding of design patterns, and I can't fault someone for that.

Comment: Sorry not working this is error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::mysqli_query() `

Comment: Because you're still using procedural functions. Please look at the documentation for OO mysqli. You need to use the mysqli::query() method.